# Python: How to change the location of multiple values in a csv file into a single line values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I would like to change the column values into a continuous single line values as such:

**input.csv**

```
0.1,0.2,0.3
0.6,0.8,0.5
0.3,0.2,0.4
```

**Desired output**

```
0.1,0.6,0.3,0.2,0.8,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.4
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: have you tried anything? :)

Comment: I tried concatenate in array but it is not in csv format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes your file is small enough, but then it is very simple:

You first read the csv in as a list of lists:

```
array = []
with open("input.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        array.append(map(float, line.split(",")))
```

And then, it is simply a matter of chaining a zip:

```
from itertools import chain
print(list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*array))))
```

<sup>P.S.: I'm sorry for my first answer, I completely misunderstood your question initially.</sup>